# Natural Remedies For Lower Muscarine?

Tags: natural-remedy

**Histamines are found in cherries among other natural foods.  By restricting such treatment can actually prevent issues in the patient.  I was hopeful to find information like this for muscarine.**

If you take a drug that blocks m1 for long periods of time and attempt to stop like [Benadryl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphenhydramine) or many [antidepressants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amitriptyline), insomnia is a likely side effect.  Are there any natural remedies for muscarine and limiting acetylcholine muscarinic receptors?

What foods to avoid or supplements to take?

[image]

Comment: Please expand on this. It is currently wholly unclear what you want to know. "Muscarine" is probably acetylcholine muscarinic receptors? Why should that be low, how? Is this about Amanita muscaria? That would be high in muscarine. Limiting that would be easy, do not eat fly agaric. Joking aside: please [edit] to explain what you want and show your prior research.

Comment: @LangLang after m1 receptor blocking occurs from a drug insonnia is a likely side effect.  How can you prevent this with natural supplements?

Comment: Getting interesting, possibly. But we need still a bit more. E.g.: What kind of drug "to stop insomnia"? How do you get to the connection to muscarine or the receptors?

Comment: @LangLangC - If I understand you correctly when you asked *what kind of drug "to stop insominia"*, I had trouble understanding that to start with, but realised the question is asking how to stop insomnia when stopping the meds which block Muscarinic receptors.  There was no comma in the sentence to break it up.  I edited to correct that

Comment: I think you misinterpret muscarinic receptors: they are naturally acetylcholine receptors. They are only called muscarinic because there is also a compound found in certain mushrooms (that you are highly unlikely to be eating casually) called muscarine that acts as a specific agonist at those receptors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Background

Muscarinic acetylcholine receptors, or mAChRs, are acetylcholine receptors that form G protein-coupled receptor complexes in the cell membranes of certain neurons ([Eglen, 2006](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1474-8673.2006.00368.x)) and other cells. They play several roles, including acting as the main end-receptor stimulated by acetylcholine released from postganglionic fibers in the [parasympathetic nervous system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasympathetic_nervous_system).

Ligands targeting the mAChR that are currently approved for clinical use include non-selective antagonists for the treatment of Parkinson's disease, atropine (to dilate the pupil for medical examinations), scopolamine (used to prevent motion sickness), and ipratropium (used in the treatment of COPD).

With regard to antipsychotics mentioned in the question's image source ([Correll, 2008](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18533766)), Olanzapine and clozapine produce robust increases in hippocampal acetylcholine release during acetylcholinesterase inhibition, while other antipsychotics, including thioridazine, have only small effects ([Johnson, et al. 2005](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejphar.2004.11.015)). Since thioridazine binds with similar high affinities to muscarinic receptors as olanzapine and clozapine, muscarinic autoreceptor blockade was ruled out as a primary mechanism ([Shirazi-Southall, et al. 2002](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0893-133X(01)00400-6)). This study compared in vitro binding affinities and functional activities of olanzapine, clozapine, thioridazine, ziprasidone, risperidone, chlorpromazine and scopolamine at muscarinic M2 receptors with their in vivo potencies to increase acetylcholine release in the rat hippocampus.

### To your question (how do you prevent insomnia with natural remedies when stopping these medications)

#### Stopping Antipsychotics

The main thing to consider, especially when talking about stopping antipsychotic medications, is that insomnia can be the least of the problems.  As indicated in the image you posted, stopping them can have withdrawal symptoms which include psychotic episodes, anxiety, and [Extrapyramidal Symptoms (EPS)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapyramidal_symptoms).  Stopping these medications should only be done under the guidance of your doctor.

#### Stopping other medications

Whatever the medication is you are stopping, if you suffer from insomnia as a withdrawal symptom, you should speak to your doctor who can advise on the best course of action.

### References

Correll, C. U. (2008). Assessing and maximizing the safety and tolerability of antipsychotics used in the treatment of children and adolescents. The Journal of clinical psychiatry, 69, 26-36. pmid: [18533766](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18533766)

Eglen, R. M. (2006). Muscarinic receptor subtypes in neuronal and non-neuronal cholinergic function. *Autonomic & Autacoid Pharmacology*. 26(3), 219-33. doi: [10.1111/j.1474-8673.2006.00368.x](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1474-8673.2006.00368.x)

Johnson, D. E., Nedza, F. M., Spracklin, D. K., Ward, K. M., Schmidt, A. W., Iredale, P. A., ... & Rollema, H. (2005). The role of muscarinic receptor antagonism in antipsychotic-induced hippocampal acetylcholine release. *European journal of pharmacology*, 506(3), 209-219. doi: [10.1016/j.ejphar.2004.11.015](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejphar.2004.11.015)

Shirazi-Southall, S., Rodriguez, D. E., & Nomikos, G. G. (2002). Effects of typical and atypical antipsychotics and receptor selective compounds on acetylcholine efflux in the hippocampus of the rat. *Neuropsychopharmacology*, 26(5), 583-594. doi: [10.1016/S0893-133X(01)00400-6](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0893-133X(01)00400-6)

Comment: Why do you assume this information is primarily applicable to antipsychotics?  Elavil and lots of antidepressants have this same effect.  I cited the only source I could find about m1 receptors withdrawal.  Natural supplements was the core of the question.

Comment: @William The source for the table in your question was about antipsychotics so it is very natural to focus there. Chris's answer, however, already is more broad. Your focus on natural supplements is misguided, there is nothing special about 'natural' anything; as Chris writes, *if you suffer from insomnia as a withdrawal symptom, you should speak to your doctor who can advise on the best course of action*.

Comment: @BryanKrause histamines are found in cherrys and lot of natural foods.  If this doesn't hold for this question okay.

Comment: I have accepted this as an answer but it appears poison mushrooms are the only natural alternative.  Over the counter options include benadryl although I wouldn't recommend that with out doctors approval.

Comment: @William I wouldn't recommend anything without doctors approval

Comment: Is it possible m1 receptors affinity just tend to exist with also h1 receptors which is why this study seems to infer it causes insomnia?